# Openshift 3.11 - edit deployment config - cant add command

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm attempting to edit the yaml of a deployment config in the OpenShift web console.

I'm simply trying to add a `command` and some `args`. I have another working example with the correct syntax and indentation.

However, when I copy this into the deployment config, Im unable to save it due to a validation error. However the error doesnt relate to the change I've made.

The error message is:

> Failed to process the resource.
>   Reason: DeploymentConfig.apps.openshift.io "my-sdk" is invalid: [spec.template.spec.containers[0].name: Required value, spec.template.spec.containers[0].image: Required value]

For example, I have the following snippet from the working deployment config:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: MY_DB_HOST
              value: postgresql
            - name: MY_DB_NAME
              value: MY
            - name: MY_DB_PASSWORD
              value: MY
            - name: MY_DB_USER
              value: MY
            - name: MY_CACHE_ENABLED
              value: 'false'
          image: >-
            172.30.1.1:5000/myapp/my-sdk@sha256:eb485f011eaab9342b7fcf272c9f22dded9c238987f1dec932f8e1640ac18251
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: my-sdk
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
```

Then I attempt to change it to the following:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
            - '-myarg'
          command:
            - node
        - env:
            - name: MY_DB_HOST
              value: postgresql
            - name: MY_DB_NAME
              value: MY
            - name: MY_DB_PASSWORD
              value: MY
            - name: MY_DB_USER
              value: MY
            - name: MY_CACHE_ENABLED
              value: 'false'
          image: >-
            172.30.1.1:5000/myapp/my-sdk@sha256:eb485f011eaab9342b7fcf272c9f22dded9c238987f1dec932f8e1640ac18251
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: my-sdk
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
```

And with this change I get the above error. 
I'm 99% certain the change I made is valid, as I'm simply coping it from a functional deployment config. And the error message doesnt seem to relate at all to the change.

## Update

Now I have a working deploymentconfig that contains `command` and `arg` values.

When I try to remove these, without modifying any other yaml, or indentation, I get the following useless validation error:

> Failed to process the resource.
>   Reason: ReplicationController in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ReplicationController: v1.ReplicationController.Spec: v1.ReplicationControllerSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.TerminationGracePeriodSeconds: SecurityContext: SchedulerName: RestartPolicy: DNSPolicy: Containers: decode slice: expect [ or n, but found {, error found in #10 byte of ...|y":"File"},"dnsPolic|..., bigger context ...|ermination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File"},"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","restartPolicy":"Alway|...

Comment: The whole `env` and `args` sections needs to be indented one more level. The '-' for those should be same indent as `command`.

Comment: It can sometimes be helpful to plugin what you want to use into https://www.json2yaml.com/ and look at the result in JSON as it more clearly shows the structure if you are not familiar with YAML.

Comment: Please update your new yaml file. Please provide your openshift and kubernetes versions.

Answer (score 0):

One example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx@sha256:e3456c851a152494c3e4ff5fcc26f240206abac0c9d794affb40e0714846c451
        env:
         - name: DEMO_GREETING
           value: "Hello from the environment"
        command: ["echo"]
        args: ["$(GREETING) $(HONORIFIC) $(NAME)"] 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Please follow documentation:
[Using environment variables inside of your config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config)

In addition please verify your spec with the image line `image: >-` as per error `image: Required value`

Answer (score 0):

In ReplicationController they should have selector (In RC Spec)  and labels ( template spec) to match the container to start. Hence based on error you may not get to know this as this would be more of generic.